# Redirect all ASP.NET Core logging into a single NLog logger

Tags: asp.net, nlog

I have an ASP.NET project that sends its logs to NLog.

However in this project, I have my own NLog logger and I would like to know how to route all the logs through it.

I guess I shouldn't add NLog as a logger, but I should find a way to register a method that will get called each time ASP tries to log anything.

How can this be accomplished?

---

This is the code that creates the logger:

```
        // create the module name
        var ProcessName = Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName;
        _ModuleName = ProcessName  + " (\"" + Oracle.GuessMyName() + "\")";

        // create the logger configuration
        var Configuration = new LoggingConfiguration();

        // create the file target
        var FileTarget = new FileTarget ("file")
        {
            FileName            = @"x:\Logs\${processname}.log",
            ArchiveFileName     = @"x:\Logs\${processname}.{#}.log",
            Layout              = @"${longdate}|${logger}|${level}|${message}${onexception:|Exception occurred:${exception:format=tostring}${newline}",
            ArchiveEvery        = FileArchivePeriod.Day,
            ArchiveNumbering    = ArchiveNumberingMode.Rolling,
            MaxArchiveFiles     = 7,
            ConcurrentWrites    = true
        };

        Configuration.AddTarget(FileTarget);


        // create the viewer target
        var ViewerTarget = new NLogViewerTarget ("viewer")
        {
            Layout              = @"${message}${onexception:${newline} --> Exception occurred\:${exception:format=tostring}",
            IncludeSourceInfo   = true,
            IncludeCallSite     = true,
            Address             = @"udp://127.0.0.1:9999"
        };

        Configuration.AddTarget(ViewerTarget);

        // set the rules
        Configuration.LoggingRules.Add(new LoggingRule("*", LogLevel.Info, FileTarget));
        Configuration.LoggingRules.Add(new LoggingRule("*", LogLevel.Info, ViewerTarget));

        // set the configuration
        LogManager.Configuration = Configuration;

        // create a new logger
        _Logger = LogManager.GetLogger(_ModuleName);
```

and this is also how ASP.net gets attached to nlog:

```
        LoggerFactory.AddNLog();
        Application.AddNLogWeb();
```

Now the current log layout looks like this for two process (the animal names are automatically changing every time the process is restarted)
[image: log layout]

so both process: shinobi and mouserun here have their own log output, but anything ASP related goes to ASP's nlog instance called Microsoft, regardless of the process.

the goal is to have the ASP output of shinobi to go in the shinobi logger and the mouserun ASP output to go in the mouserun logger.

Comment: no, I wanted anything that goes to Microsoft from the Shinobi process to go to the Shinobi logger and anything that goes to Microsoft from Mouserun to go to the Mouserun process. I don't want ASP to log to nlog, I want ASP to give me a callback when it wants to log something so I can write to the process' logger

Comment: Add so it is the Log4J XML output that contain a logger-name that you somehow have configured everything around. The file-target is working just fine.

Comment: yes, the file output is working fine, but the UDP one is not

Comment: No way that you can change the logic to use NLogViewerTarget.Parameters to inject the global application name, and then extract it from the Log4J XML in the viewer ? Maybe have it as an override, so if the global-application-parameter-element exists then it is use, else it falls back to the logger-element.

Comment: no practical way to do this; the easiest is probably to remove the ASP/Nlog integration and then make an ASP middleware for the logging that will just write to the process' logger (at least from what I'm seeing on google, that seems to be the most straightforward)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the code of NLog.Extensions.Logging, where it injects its own custom log-provider.

You can do the same and just wrap your global-logger object:

https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Extensions.Logging/blob/e48d6cc54d9abd70d976066265c7992117cbac5a/src/NLog.Extensions.Logging/NLogLoggerProvider.cs

https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Extensions.Logging/blob/1474ffe5b26d2ac95534ed01ef259133133bfb67/src/NLog.Extensions.Logging/NLogLoggerFactory.cs

https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Extensions.Logging/blob/2c05a4fbdda0fe026e60814d535e164e18786aef/src/NLog.Extensions.Logging/ConfigureExtensions.cs

```
    public static ILoggerFactory AddNLog(this ILoggerFactory factory, NLogProviderOptions options)
    {
        ConfigureHiddenAssemblies();

        using (var provider = new NLogLoggerProvider(options))
        {
            factory.AddProvider(provider);
        }
        return factory;
    }
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed! thanks a lot for all the time you spent looking into this!

Comment: Created https://github.com/NLog/NLog/pull/2390 so you can do the override of LoggerName directly on NLogViewerTarget.

Comment: @Thomas NLog 4.5 RC has been released, that includes the above PR, so now you don't need to implement your own extension logic to override the logger-name in the NLogViewerTarget. Just use NLogViewerTarget.LoggerName

Answer (score 0):

You could also create a custom-target, and redirect all non-global-logger messages to this target using NLog rules:

https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/Configuration-file#rules

The custom target can then just forward the log-event to the global-logger:

https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/How-to-write-a-custom-target

You should be careful with cyclic logging. Maybe have a filter in the custom-target to ignore messages from the global-logger.

But I think this is an ugly solution, and I fail to understand the restriction of only one logger-object. Especially when the reason is because it should be named after the application. Why not not a global variable for the name instead of abusing the logger-name?

Comment: The reason is that on the same system there are a few programs using the same lib, which centralizes logging, running at the same time; and at each new execution of this programs, we need a new log file. So when the app starts, it generates a name (it's base name + a random part) and anything output from this specific instance has to go through a logger named that way (we need UDP + files output).

Comment: the system works very well but for ASP because the Nlog integration creates a logger instance called 'Microsoft' and anything ASP related go through it, merging the ASP outputs of all the apps in the UDP logger since the data is sorted by logger name

Comment: so, the current solution works, but I just need a hook in ASP so that *I* can log it's log output instead of ASP doing it directly. For this, I would remove the ASP/Nlog integration and for every message I receive, I'd just forward it to the app instance's logger

Comment: Still don't understand why the NLog-logger-name is directly bound to the UDP-target + file-target. Why not just fix the NLog-config of those targets, so they don't use the Logger-name?

Comment: the name is defined like this: @"x:\Logs\${processname}.log"; there is not even a nlog config file, it's code setting up the logger so that its output matches precisely the current process; this is done when generating a global instance of the logger for that process; since this is used everywhere, it's not something that can be changed (nor would there be a point with the way the system is used anyways)

Comment: that logger is global to the process so every log info goes specifically to that file. Since the ASP/Nlog integration creates a new log, this means that now a process has two log outputs

Comment: Then change the code that adds the file-target to the NLog-configuration so the filename is not based on the logger-name. I still don't understand why you need a global logger-name.

Comment: Please append the code that setup your NLog-configuration to your question. Creation of targets, creation of logging-rules, and creation of the infamous global-logger.

Comment: I added a lot more details

Answer (score 0):

Alternative you can create a custom target wrapper, that fixes the Logger on LogEventInfo's, so when forwarded to the wrapped target (UDP- / File-target), then it looks like they are all come from the same logger.

Similar to what this guy is trying to do:

https://github.com/NLog/NLog/issues/2352

Again really ugly solution, and should only be used when not able to figure out, how to avoid using the logger-name in the configuration of the wanted Nlog-targets (Ex. configure file-target-filename using something else).